# Rails error "could nof find pg-0.18.3 in any of the sources" after Nginx restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, rubygems, passenger

I'm trying to setup Rails 4.2 on Nginx for a while now. Every time I start a fresh install with RVM it gets fine. I can run `rake db:create:all` and create the databases. But if I restart Nginx using `/etc/init.d/nginx restart`, Passenger sends me an error about a gem :

```
It looks like Bundler could not find a gem. Maybe you didn't install all the gems that this application needs. To install your gems, please run:

bundle install

If that didn't work, then the problem is probably caused by your application being run under a different environment than it's supposed to. Please check the following:

    Is this app supposed to be run as the www-data user?
    Is this app being run on the correct Ruby interpreter? Below you will see which Ruby interpreter Phusion Passenger attempted to use.

-------- The exception is as follows: -------
Could not find pg-0.18.3 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:140:in `specs'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `specs_for'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in `requested_specs'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:127:in `setup'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:411:in `activate_gem'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:295:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:416:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:294:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:99:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:153:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

The pg gem is already installed in my **Gemfile** and in RVM :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'

gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.3'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

gem 'execjs'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Then if I run `gem query --local` I get `pg (0.18.3)`

**config/database.yml** :

```
login: &login
  adapter: postgresql
  username: myuser
  password: mypass
  host: localhost
  encoding: UTF8

development:
  <<: *login
  database: mydb_dev

test:
  <<: *login
  database: mydb_test

production:
  <<: *login
  database: mydb_prod
```

**rvm info :**

```
  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.2.1p85"
    date:         "2015-02-26"
    platform:     "x86_64-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2015-02-26 revision 49769"
    full_version: "ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1"
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/root/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1"
    GEM_PATH:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1"
    IRBRC:        "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
```

Am I doing something wrong when I try to restart Nginx ?

Comment: please post the complete gemfile and database.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have the gem installed, but your bundler isn't finding it when you restart.

A few ideas:

- have you performed a bundle in your gemfile directory? Try running `bundle exec gem list` to see what's actually in your bundle, and not just what's installed locally (which is what you see with `gem query --local`).
- check that you have a default version of ruby set by rvm that matches what's being bundled with. It's possible that, when you restart, it's defaulting to the wrong Ruby version (and then looking in the wrong path)

Comment: Hum you may be right. Running rvm gemdir : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1 then running which gem : /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/gem and which ruby : /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby. rvm gemdir doesn't match the right gem folder, isn't it ?